# JDOM get string of containing content

Tags: java, xml, jdom

lets say I have some xml:

```
<document>blabla<bold>test<list><item>hello<italics>dfh</italics></item></list></bold>sdfsd</document>
```

and I now need to get the content of  as a string, so I would have

```
blabla<bold>test<list><item>hello<italics>dfh</italics></item></list></bold>sdfsd
```

i have been messing with this in my head for a while now, and I haven't seem to be able to figure it out.

Hope to get some directions to what I have to do.

EDIT:

just to be clear, lets say I have the XML like this:

```
SAXBuilder sb = new SAXBuilder();
Document doc = sb.build(new StringReader("<document>blabla<bold>test<list><item>hello<italics>dfh</italics></item></list></bold>sdfsd</document>"));
```

and I now need to get the content of

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is very unusual to need to get an inconsistent subset of an XML document like you want. It's much more common to get just the text content: `blabla test hello dfh sdfsd`

Note that you can get a subset of the content as the "contentlist" of the root element, and then output just that list as a string:

```
    XMLOutputter xout = new XMLOutputter();
    String txt = xout.outputString(doc.getRootElement().getContent());
    System.out.println(txt);
```

For me, I wrote the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JDOMException, IOException {
    SAXBuilder sb = new SAXBuilder();
    Document doc = sb.build(new StringReader("<document>blabla<bold>test<list><item>hello<italics>dfh</italics></item></list></bold>sdfsd</document>"));

    XMLOutputter xout = new XMLOutputter();
    String txt = xout.outputString(doc.getRootElement().getContent());
    System.out.println(txt);        
}
```

and it output:

> ```
> blabla<bold>test<list><item>hello<italics>dfh</italics></item></list></bold>sdfsd
> ```